# Placing divs horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have this div in my html code and it automatically repeate in the webpage because I fetch data from database. But it displays that vertically and I want it to be horizontally.

I tried using different css properties like ***inline-block***, ***float*** and ***flex-direction*** none of them seems to work.

This is the html code that I have

```
    <div class="slider">
    <figure>

        <div class="img-container">
            <h3> <?php echo $row['title'];  ?> </h3>

            <p style="inline-size: 600px; "> <?php echo $row['description'];  ?> </p>
        </div>

    </figure>
    </div>
```

and this is the css

```
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Rubik','Noto Sans Arabic', sans-serif;
    color: #444444;
}

.slider{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}


.img-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
}

.slider figure{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    width: 500%;
    animation: entrance 1s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes entrance{
    
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-250px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

    
}
```

I don't know if it's not working because I only have one div in my code. If so, can you please tell me how I can do this otherwise? because I did try to add more than one and it's not working either.

Comment: You surely don't need to target both `.slider figure div {}` *and* `.img-container {}`? Those are the same things.

Comment: Another approach to this would be setting the 'figure' (not sure you're semantically using that tag correctly, btw) to a row flexbox with overflow: scroll (or auto). That's the easiest way to create a 'native' type of carousel/slider.

Comment: Where is the php loop? Does it go around the `div. img-container` (within the `<figure>`)?

Comment: @NicolasGoosen Yeah I made a silly mistake by targeting the same thing in css, I deleted the first. I use the tag "figure" because I want to make image/text slideshow, but I'm trying to make animation work for text first before I add the images from database.

Comment: @NicolasGoosen The php loop I have is this:  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { 
 }

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to display horizontally and equally spaced you can do something like this. Also, I'm explicitly setting figure margin and padding as 0 but you can modify a/q to your needs. This is just to show how to place elements horizontally.

```css
body,figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Dummy</h3>
    <p> This is a para</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Dummy</h3>
    <p> This is a para</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Dummy</h3>
    <p> This is a para</p>
  </div>
</figure>
```

Comment: Kudos @innocent, I didn't know about the `gap` property for Flexbox. I've always done `.container > div { margin-right: xx }` then `.container > div:last-child { margin-right: 0 }`. Going to use `gap` from now on!

Comment: This code works perfectly with text that I type in code, but when I try to put text from database it keeps displaying it vertically. It's the same with every code I tried. Do you know why is it causing this? I looked up but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: @SaraA Are you adding it correctly. Try to add any other style to it and test if its working. Can you add a minimum reproducable example?

Answer (score 0):

you set `overflow: hidden;` in your `.slider` class. and `.img-container` class you set to `100vh` witch takes all your screen.

try to remove this properties and define the `<figure>` element as:
`display:flex; flex-direction:column;`

Answer (score 0):

Use flex. do you want like this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Rubik', 'Noto Sans Arabic', sans-serif;
  color: #444444;
}

.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  border: solid red;
}

.img-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  border: solid;
}

h3 {
  border: solid yellow;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
}

p {
  border: solid green;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
}

.slider figure {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: entrance 1s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes entrance {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-250px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <figure>

      <div class="img-container">
        <h3> some title </h3>

        <p> some description </p>
      </div>

    </figure>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Arman, thanks for your help. It sadly does not work. Like most of the different functions i used, for regular text you type in code, it works fine. But when I display text from database, it goes back to vertical.

Comment: @SaraA I don't know about `php`. But can you show your code in code-snippet for more help from others? Also, I suggests adding `php` tag to your tags.